# How to debug llvm source?

Tags: gdb, llvm, debug-symbols

I have build llvm debug version with configue --enable-debug-runtime. I want to learn the exetution process of llvm by the gdb stack trace ? But occured error when I using gdb:

```
llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin$ gdb ./clang
(gdb) b clang::CreateLLVMCodeGen (...)
(gdb) r ./clang ~/tmp/helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

Can any one help me? Thanks.

Comment: What error occurred?

Comment: Gdb said can not find the c source file and the symbols

Comment: You have a release version of the clang which has no debug symbols. You have to remove the `--enable-optimized` flag when you run `configure` to get a debug version.

Comment: I did it, configure without --enable-optimized flag.

Comment: `llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/` says you have an optimized build

Comment: Thank you very mach. What directory does the debug mode generate? How can I explicit disable the optimized tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue you're going to have in trying to debug clang is that the first invocation of clang spawns another clang process. What you should do is use clang -v to get the -cc1 command line and use that as your run arguments in gdb.

As far as the Release+Asserts bit, you'll want to do this configure line:

```
configure --enable-debug-symbols --disable-optimized
```

since you appear to be using release sources of llvm. The defaults change versus the bits in svn.

Asserts are useful anyhow, so I'd keep them in.

Answer (score 2):

`set follow-fork-mode child` [would work](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html), too. That way, you don't bother to figure out what follows `-cc1`.